# Pymongo query taking too long

Tags: python, mongodb

right now I have a problem on how to make a find query return the results faster and I don't know exactly how I can do it. I'm fairly new to both MongoDB and python so please bear with me. I have a collection on MongoDB with 250000 objects. Each one is fairly nested. They are something like this:

```
_id: Objectid
shopper: Shopperid
data:{ 
report:{
items:{
accounts:{
account_1:{
mask:
type:
subtype:
inst_id:
historical_balances:{
object_1
object_2
...}
}
account_2:{
mask:
type:
subtype:
inst_id:
historical_balances:{
object_1
object_2
...}
...
}
}
}
}
```

And I need to get those data and the sum of historical balances for each account on each object. Right now it is taking forever and I don't know exactly what to do. I am trying to download locally the data from MongoDB but every time my internet has a connection problem all is lost and it's taking more than 10 hours to get to half of it. I tried using list(find(query)) so I could deal with it later but I don't have enough ram. Right now what I am doing is:

```
for k in cursor:
    for j in range(len(k['data']['report']['items'][0]['accounts'])):
        e.append([k['_id'], k['shopper'],k['data']['report']['items'][0]['institution_id'], 
k['data']['report']['items'][0]['institution_name'], 
k['data']['report']['items'][0]['accounts'][j]['mask'], 
k['data']['report']['items'][0]['accounts'][j]['type'], 
k['data']['report']['items'][0]['accounts'][j]['subtype'], len(k['data']['report']['items'][0]['accounts'][j]['transactions'])])
```

In summary: Each object has a data field that has a report field, that has a items field that has an account field, each account field has multiple accounts objects that have a mask, type, subtype and historical balances. I need all this data and a sum of historical balances for each account.

Right now I am using the code above to get data, put into a list and then turn it into a Panda Dataframe so I can save as a csv file which is what I need. I know it isn't the prettiest code but it was the first idea I came up with. Any ideas on how I can improve this performance that is being really slow for my needs?

Comment: So, you want to retrieve the entire collection with the only processing being replacing `"...historical_balances"` with a sum of the balances?

Comment: Pretty much, yes

Comment: How do you plan to represent nested fields in the CSV?

Comment: I ended up finishing it but I want to improve the speed it happens. I got the data I needed, put into a list and turned into a panda Dataframe so in the end it became just a table